# BsonDateTimeOptions doesn't set local datetime

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core, mongodb-.net-driver

Although I decorated my `Datetime` property with `BsonDateTimeOptions` , it still does not work and time inserted to database, 3 hours behind my local time.(I think it is utc)
My base abstract class

```
public abstract class MongoBaseModel
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }

    [BsonElement]
    [BsonDateTimeOptions(Kind = DateTimeKind.Local)]
    public DateTime InsertedAt{ get; set; }
}
```

My Entity

```
public class RockSongs:MongoBaseModel
{
    [BsonElement("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("Singer")]
    public string Singer { get; set; }
}
```

[image]

Db version v4.2.1

MongoDb.Driver 2.7.2

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/model-time-data/):

> MongoDB stores times in UTC by default, and will convert any local time representations into this form. Applications that must operate or report on some unmodified local time value may store the time zone alongside the UTC timestamp, and compute the original local time in their application logic.

There is no difference between `DateTimeKind.Local` and `DateTimeKind.Utc` when it comes to **serialization**. In both cases your .NET `DateTime` will be stored as UTC. The moment when this attribute becomes useful is **deserialization**. MongoDB .NET driver will automatically convert your UTC date time into your local computer's timezone if you apply `DateTimeKind.Local`.

The fact that MongoDB stores dates as UTC comes directly from [BSON](http://bsonspec.org/spec.html) specification.

Comment: So there is no possibility to store it to db as local time ?

Comment: @erhan355 Basically I wouldn't recommend that. Date time stored in databases should be client-agnostic and "local time" is something that should be calculated on a client side. Please take a look at linked example where it is recommended to store offset as a separate field so that your client app can easily convert to local time.

Comment: @erhan355 like mickl said, you shouldn't store localtime in the db but if you really must, have a look at this [custom date serializer](https://github.com/dj-nitehawk/MongoDB.Entities/blob/master/MongoDB.Entities/Utilities/Date.cs) i've written. you can change line 26 and line 40 to get rid of the conversion to utc.

Comment: @Ryan Gunner I partially agree.In some cases I think you really need it.Imagine that I have  a web application that logs sensor values and insert it to cloud.Other cloud service periodically fetchs data and  when any sensor threshold are exceeded it sends a mail which consists of timestamp at which threshold was exceeded.In this case, datetime zone will always be the cloud service's time zone and customers will receive mails with wrong datetime. Am I wrong ?

Comment: @erhan355 perfect example. That's why it's recommended to store UTC in your DB and convert to local on a client side

Comment: @erhan355 when multiple timezones are involved, it's best to store it as utc and when displaying to users convert it back to local time of the user. for that you must know the timezone of the user and do the conversion like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/datetime/converting-between-time-zones#converting-utc-to-a-designated-time-zone).

Comment: Let's say I already put DateTime.Utc to my DateTime property. Yet my local time is not UTC. BSON converts my UTC time to UTC again. So, is there any way to tell BSON to not mess with my DateTime?